Purge request body from Swagger Editor (OpenAPI 3) produced CURL
Try out for my path in Swagger Editor (OpenAPI 3.0 yml loaded) produces the following CURL:
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:84/query?org=influx&pretty=true&db=influx&q=select%20%2A%20from%20connection' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: Token my_real_token' \
  -d ''

This output produced when no request body present for path at all.
Unfortunately, -d '' strongly not required here. Empty data is not enough to normal work.
How to purge -d from Swagger Editor / Swagger UI generated CURL ?
UPDATE:
Here is complete endpoint:
/query:
    post:
      tags:
        - "Work with InfluxDB"
      summary: Read info from Influx (v1)
      security:
        - influx: []
      parameters:
        - name: org
          description: Org name
          required: true
          in: query
          schema:
            type: string
            default: influx
            readOnly: true
        - name: pretty
          description: Prettier output flag
          required: true
          in: query
          schema:
            type: string
            default: true
        - name: db
          description: DB Name
          in: query
          schema:
            type: string
            default: influx
            readOnly: true
        - name: q
          description: InfluxQL code
          in: query
          schema:
            type: string
            default: select * from connection
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Data from Influx read
        '401':
          description: |
            Unauthorized access to Influx.

            Did you forget to authorize?
    servers:
      - url: http://localhost:84

UPDATE2:
This code is acceptable by InfluxDB:
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:84/query?org=influx&pretty=true&db=influx&q=select%20%2A%20from%20connection' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: Token my_real_token'

Here no -d

Can you post the OpenAPI definition of your POST /query endpoint? Did you write the OpenAPI file manually or generate it from code?

@Helen. Wrote complete endpoint. .yml wrote manually by OpenApi 3.0 spec. Now is about 30 endpoints and 2000+ lines of .yml code

Open an issue in the Swagger UI repo https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues. This might be a bug. Alternatively, a new config option might be needed to control whether cURL commands should include -d '' if no requestBody is defined for an endpoint. The source code lines responsible for the current behavior are here.

Thanks to @Helen.
My case is an issue of Swagger UI (((
